# How do I force a section of unfinished code to run even under max optimizations?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, compiler-optimization

I have a function in my program that preforms a whole bunch of floating point math. It returns an array of values which is not currently being used in my program yet.

I want to test this piece of code for speed under maximum optimizations, however since the code isn't used, the compiler conveniently skips the function all together and I can't get a time on it.

How do force the compiler to run that section of code under maximum optimizations even though the result is not used (I want the computer to just give me a sense as to how fast the section runs).

I'm running Visual C++ 2008.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use the result? How do you propose that you benchmark truly maximum optimizations if you intend to disable one or more of them (removing unused code)?

Comment: I was thinking of more of a hack than a neat way: If it returns a bunch of floating point math, when it returns this, use rand() to print 1 floating point from the array. That way the compiler can never leave out any computations, as it doesn't know which one it will need later on. I do not know of an "elegant" way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are many compiler tricks, but the easiest way is to just make it look like you are using the value. In this case, just pass the returned array to some other function. The other function doesn't need to do anything, but that should be enough to convince the compiler you need the results.

If you find that your empty second function is being optimized out as well, then just stick it in a shared library (DLL) and it is impossible for the compiler to know how it is being used.

How you allocate the result can also change this. If you pass the original function a pointer, you could just pass it a heap pointer. Since that pointer may be used somewhere else it is highly unlikely the compiler could optimize away the code, as it has no idea if the results will be used or not.

---

You could also just legitimately use the data. It makes sense to verify the results in another function. If doing performance testing just put this verification part outside of the timed section. This is generally how I do such performance tests (make sure the result is checked/used).

Comment: So it sounds like the simple answer is to actually use the results in some way...ok, I can live with that. I'll create a variable that sums up each of the results and prints it at the end of the program.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`SecureZeroMemory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to overwrite the result after is has been received from the function. You don't even need to overwrite the whole result, one array element will be enough, maybe you can even pass zero as "number of bytes", so that nothing is done by the function.

This will do the trick on Windows - `SecureZeroMemory()` is intended to never be optimized out by the compiler. Using it is pretty straightforward and it's rather fast.

Answer (score 2):

This is what a test case is for. Write a test case in a separate binary (even just in the main() method) which sets a throwaway local variable to the result of the function. Time using your preferred method (e.g by capturing time(NULL) from  immediately before and after the assignment and printing the time difference). You should have a decent idea of running time from that.

*EDIT*: time(NULL) is whole-second precision = bad and evil. Use clock(), as shown [here](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1048385167&id=1043284392), for the most accurate precision in the C/C++ standard library.

Comment: I recommend running the code in a loop when you time it. It's way too easy to get false reads and random error when you're dealing with such small time intervals.

Comment: The compiler may still ignore the result if it sees it isn't being used by the test function.

Comment: +1 Cody, definitely run the assignment multiple times. That should also help to give the compiler a hint that it should not be optimised out.

Comment: Just nitpicking, `clock` is part of the standard library, but not the STL (Standard Template Library). The STL is an extension to the original standard library, and as such only a subset of it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using visual studio the code down here would work, but idon't know about any other solutions for gcc

```
#pragma optimize( "", off )
.
.
.
#pragma optimize( "", on )
```